# How to show clicked image in viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, imageview, gallery

I have a recycler view in activity_main.xml with a few images. When I click any of the image I go to another activity which has a viewpager. The problem is whenever I click any image the viewpager show images from the starting. I want to show the image that has been clicked just like in google photos or any other gallery app. It will be great if anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bro Have You Solved this? I'm Working on this now. If it solved, pls post the solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess (because you didn't post any code) that you are loading your images from an url, so when you click an image you start a new a activity. If that guess is correct then I would put the url of the selected image into an extra param and then add it to the intent, so when the new activity comes out I can get that value again and just show that image.
Extra parameters for intents work like this, first add the value that you want to send to the other activity:

```
// MainActivity
Intent intent = new 
Intent(getContext(), 
pictureActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("key",                        
"website.com/image.jpg");

getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the other activity you have to get the value that you put into the extra:

```
// PictureActivity
if (getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {
  String url =  
  getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
}
```

The next thing I would is just take the url and inflate the image into the image view or wherever you want it to be shown. I hope that I can be helpful enough to put you in the right direction.